# com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer max connection count?

Tags: java, com.sun.net.httpserver

Sometimes (pretty rarely) when I connect to a running instance of a com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer I get a "connection refused" message back.

Anybody know why this might be? Is there a thread limit to the number of connections it can  handle? Can I increase it?
Thanks.
-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the doc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html):

> When binding to an address and port
>   number, the application can also
>   specify an integer backlog parameter.
>   This represents the maximum number of
>   incoming TCP connections which the
>   system will queue internally.
>   Connections are queued while they are
>   waiting to be accepted by the
>   HttpServer. When the limit is reached,
>   further connections may be rejected
>   (or possibly ignored) by the
>   underlying TCP implementation. Setting
>   the right backlog value is a
>   compromise between efficient resource
>   usage in the TCP layer (not setting it
>   too high) and allowing adequate
>   throughput of incoming requests (not
>   setting it too low).

You may be seeing this.

*Alternatively*, have you set an executor using [setExecutor()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#setExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29). The default executor may have fewer threads configured than you need, and a suitably-configured [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) may work.

Comment: setExecutor--thank you very much--wonder what the default configuration is... [the java docs, as usual, with " a default implementation is used"]

Comment: I just experienced different default behavior on two versions of OpenJDK (Ubuntu 12.04 and ArchLinux -- "1.7.0_21" vs "1.7.0_15"): on Ubuntu it worked as expected but on ArchLinux the default is apparently single-threaded?? Setting the Executor to use a thread pool solved the problem.